# How can I show inside of System.Object[] Powershell, invoke-webrequest

Tags: json, csv, powershell

My code is like this

```
       $username = "username"
        $password = "password"

        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/Ateam/members -Method Get

$new = $response |select Values 

$new

$new|Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\Ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

when I execute this script, I can see the inside of "Values" like this on my Powershell Board.

```
values                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{@{username=helloworld; website=; display_name=rhelloworld; uuid ={dewi3urgfj-.
```

but I checked my csv, it says like this

```
values
System.Object[]
```

I would like to show on my csv like this also,

```
 {@{username=helloworld; website=; display_name=rhelloworld; uuid ={dewi3urgfj-.
```

How can I show inside of "System Object[]" on my csv like when I execute "$new"?

Comment: Have you tried `ConvertFrom-Json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional property 'values' in your object $new. At the moment it is exporting 'values' as a column an then the list of objects as a cell.

You could convert your cell to JSON like this:

```
$new.values  = $new.values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

But personally I don't see why you would want to export to a CSV like this. It is hardly readable and CSV has just one column and one line.

Are you sure you don't just want to export the list of objects to a CSV like this:

```
$new.values | Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\Ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I do not want to export data like you mentioned. So I made another question, if you know please let me know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752724/how-to-change-json-to-csv-powershell

Comment: I think there is something wrongly understood.Can you post the whole JSON that is returned from your Webservice and then explain how you want the csv to look like ? Only after you need to search for how to do the conversion to csv

Comment: I tried like this $csvinfo = $new.values| ConvertFrom-Json |select username,username,website,display_name,uuid,l inks__hooks,l inks__self,l inks__repositories  |Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation  The error is Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

Comment: This is not good.You are doing far to many conversions. Forget my answer.Try to step back, think what you want to do, edit your post with the response the web service is sending,add to your post how you want the csv to look like and then (and only then) someone can help you with the code you need.

Comment: @Thank you so much your help!!!!! I found out the way!!!! This was exactly I want.$new.values = $new.values |ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$csv = $new.values| ConvertFrom-JSON
$csv|Export-Csv .................... -NoTypeinformation