# How to change JSON to CSV?

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have a code like this

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/Ateam/members -Method Get

$new = $response | select Values

$new.values = $new.values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$new.values

$csvinfo = (Get-Content $new.values | ConvertFrom-Json) |
           Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation

$csvinfo | Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\Ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

@$new.values,

I can see JSON file on my screen, I would like to change to CSV file, like above, I tried

```
 $csvinfo = (Get-Content $new.values | ConvertFrom-Json) |
            Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

but it says

```
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '[{"username"' does not
exist.
At line:14 char:13
+ $csvinfo = (Get-Content $new.values | ConvertFrom-Json) | Convertto-CSV
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ([{"username":String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

How can I change `$new.values` to CSV and export?

**I found the answer**

```
$csv = $new.values| ConvertFrom-JSON
$csv|Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `$new.values` is JSON data - `$new.values = $new.values |ConvertTo-Json -Compress`. You can't have a filename that is a JSON object. And `Get-Content` is expecting a filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell convertfrom-json | convertto-csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485004/powershell-convertfrom-json-convertto-csv)

Answer (score 0):

add this

I was thinking too much....

```
$csv = $new.values| ConvertFrom-JSON
$csv|Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You could probably just skip the `$csv` variable: `$new.values| ConvertFrom-JSON | Export-Csv C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\BitBucket\ateam.team.csv -NoTypeInformation`.