# How to Open/the difference @{diff..... and {@{..... convertFrom-json to csv file

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have a code and if I execute this

```
$linksjson =$csv|select links

$linksjson
```

output is

```
links                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
@{diff=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/diff/1234}; self=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234}...
@{self=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234}; comments=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234...
@{self=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234}; comments=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234...
@{diff=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/diff/1234}; self=@{href=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/commit/1234}...
```

and other valuable

```
$parentsjson =$csv|select parents

$parentsjson
```

the output is

```
{@{hash=de6eeb97; type=commit; links=}, @{hash=f6102; type=commit; links=}}
```

The difference between $linksjson and $parentsjson is "**@{** " or "**{@{**"   ,

For $linksjson, so I tried [http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/08/use-powershell-to-convert-to-or-from-json.aspx][1], after googled, I think this is json file,so I did like this

```
$linksjson    
$openlinks=$linksjson|convertFrom-json
$openlinks
```

but the error says

```
convertFrom-json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
```

For $parentsjson, like [How can I show inside of System.Object[] Powershell, invoke-webrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748251/how-can-i-show-inside-of-system-object-powershell-invoke-webrequest)
I tried

```
$parentsjson =$csv|select parents

$parentsjson.parents =$parentsjson.parents|ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$openparents=$parentsjson.parents|ConvertFrom-JSON

$openparents
```

The error is

```
Property 'parents' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
```

How can I fix this error? I would like to see the output like for $openlinks

```
diff:.....
self:.....
```

and for $openparents

```
hash:........
type:........
links:..........
```

**REedited**

```
**$csv is coming from**

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/helloworld/$NewArray/commits

    $new = $response|select Values

    $new.values= $new.values |ConvertTo-Json -Compress

    $csv = $new.values| ConvertFrom-JSON

    $csv
```

Comment: What is `$csv`? Where did it come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you so much for helping me, I edited, if you knwo the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your $linksjson.links actually contains hashtables, but the URLs will need quotes around them to be useful. something like this might be a place to start.

```
$link = '@{diff=@{href="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/diff/1234"};self=@{href="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/diff/1234"}}'
# this converts the hashtable string into a powershell hashtable object
Invoke-Expression $link
# and if you wanted, you could do this
Invoke-Expression $link | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: How can I add '' on $parentsjson, so your code will work?